# what is this type of "var _0xc3e1=..." script in javascript tag?

Tags: javascript

what is this type of javascript  in this website  http://e-pnrstatus.com/
which look like below

```js
var _0xc3e1 = ["\x73\x68\x6F\x77", "\x74\x6F\x67\x67\x6C\x65", "\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x4C\x69\x73\x74", "\x6D\x79\x44\x72\x6F\x70\x64\x6F\x77\x6E", "\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x42\x79\x49\x64", "\x6F\x6E\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B", "\x2E\x64\x72\x6F\x70\x62\x74\x6E", "\x6D\x61\x74\x63\x68\x65\x73", "\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74", "\x64\x72\x6F\x70\x64\x6F\x77\x6E\x2D\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74", "\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x43\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x4E\x61\x6D\x65", "\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68", "\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x61\x69\x6E\x73", "\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65"];

function myFunction() {
  document[_0xc3e1[4]](_0xc3e1[3])[_0xc3e1[2]][_0xc3e1[1]](_0xc3e1[0])
}
window[_0xc3e1[5]] = function(_0xd9a9x2) {
  if (!_0xd9a9x2[_0xc3e1[8]][_0xc3e1[7]](_0xc3e1[6])) {
    var _0xd9a9x3 = document[_0xc3e1[10]](_0xc3e1[9]);
    var _0xd9a9x4;
    for (_0xd9a9x4 = 0; _0xd9a9x4 < _0xd9a9x3[_0xc3e1[11]]; _0xd9a9x4++) {
      var _0xd9a9x5 = _0xd9a9x3[_0xd9a9x4];
      if (_0xd9a9x5[_0xc3e1[2]][_0xc3e1[12]](_0xc3e1[0])) {
        _0xd9a9x5[_0xc3e1[2]][_0xc3e1[13]](_0xc3e1[0])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *"what is this type of javascript"* It is hard to read and perfectly valid. That's what it is, and that's what its purpose is.

Comment: It has been Obfuscated by the owner, because of this it is hard to read. Check this to know more https://javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [obfuscated code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)). Developers use it trying to prevent others from reading and understanding their code, because JavaScript is always readable in uncompiled form and thus this is the best way to keep your algorithms private and still use them.